# Change Window.print() paper orientation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change paper mode (orientation) on the window print. I want to change it programatically but i could not find anything.

> window.print()

But i do not know , how can i do it.

```
@media print{@page {size: landscape}}
```

I dont need it.

```
    function printWindow()
    {
        window.print({
        /*
        some code here?
        */
        });
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think that's something you can do.  Paper size and orientation are up to the user.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to inject style to your document.

```
var css = '@page { size: landscape; }',
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';
style.media = 'print';

if (style.styleSheet){
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

head.appendChild(style);

window.print();

//don't forget to find and remove style if you don't want all you documents stay in landscape
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/vc4jjhpn/](https://jsfiddle.net/vc4jjhpn/1/)

Answer (score 10):

the simplest way to change page print orientation is by using following CSS

```
@page {
    size: 25cm 35.7cm;
    margin: 5mm 5mm 5mm 5mm; /* change the margins as you want them to be. */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This one worked for me, was generating an A1 sales summary sheet

```js
var head = '<html><head>' 
      + $("head").html() 
      + ' <style>body{background-color:white !important;}@page { size: 84.1cm 59.4cm;margin: 1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm; }</style></head>';

//Additional code here......
```

Just inject the current head css so that your data does not lose the previous styling